# Como posso mudar a posição da legenda do LineChart JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

estou criando utilizando o JFreeChart para criar gráficos de linha, mas estou tendo dificuldade em personalizar a posição da legenda.
Atualmente o meu gráfico esta assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas preciso que a legenda fique no canto inferior esquerdo. Como posso personalizar?

```
//grafico da media de um periodo

public JFreeChart graficoPeriodoDeCrescimento(List<Formulario> lista,
                                                        String titulo,
                                                        String labelBottom,
                                                        String labelLeft) {
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

    try {
        for (Formulario formulario : lista) {
            System.out.println("estou percorrendo a lista");
            dataset.addValue(formulario.getCrescimento(), "Média", formulario.getDataInicial());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "deu pau no grafico");
    }

    graficoDeLinha = ChartFactory.createLineChart(titulo, labelBottom, labelLeft, dataset,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);

    // fonte
    Font fonteNova = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 18);

    CategoryItemRenderer renderer = graficoDeLinha.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer();

    CategoryPlot plot = graficoDeLinha.getCategoryPlot();

    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.GREEN);
    plot.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(12.0, 12.0, 5.0, 5.0));
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.RED);
    // cor e linha das séries
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLUE);
    renderer.setSeriesStroke(0,
            new BasicStroke(1.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER, 10.f, dash, 0.0f));
    renderer.setSeriesPositiveItemLabelPosition(0,
            new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.CENTER, TextAnchor.BASELINE_CENTER));
    renderer.setSeriesOutlineStroke(0,
            new BasicStroke(2.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER, 10.f, dash, 0.0f));
    renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(0, Color.GREEN);

    // legendas
    LegendItemCollection legendas = new LegendItemCollection();
    LegendItem legenda1 = new LegendItem("Crescimento");
    legenda1.setSeriesIndex(0);
    legenda1.setFillPaint(Color.BLUE);
    legenda1.setLabelPaint(Color.BLUE);
    legenda1.setLabelFont(fonteNova);
    legendas.add(legenda1);

    plot.setFixedLegendItems(legendas);

    return graficoDeLinha;

}
```

Comment: Por favor, apresente um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel testar o problema.

Comment: O que os métodos `getCrescimento()` e `getDataInicial()` fornecem? Como e onde está declarada a variável `graficoDeLinha`?

Comment: o getCrescimento me fornece um float que uso para preencher o gráfico com os valores; o getDataInicial retorna uma String com a data na qual o getCrescimento foi anotado, no caso retorna o ano igual a imagem acima